# Spring Custom Validator Not Working

Tags: annotations, spring-boot, spring-validator

I am trying to create custom Validator For validating Only Numbers For Field in Form.

**OnlyNumber.java** (Annotation)

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { OnlyNumberValidator.class })
public @interface OnlyNumber {

String message() default "Enter only Numbers";

 Class<?>[] groups() default {};

 Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

**OnlyNumberValidator.java** (Validator)

```
public class OnlyNumberValidator implements ConstraintValidator<OnlyNumber, Long> {

@Override
public void initialize(OnlyNumber o) {

}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Long str, ConstraintValidatorContext c) {

    System.out.println("Inside OnlyNumberValidator Str "+str);

    try 
    {

        //logic goes here

        return true;

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

**User.java** (Pojo)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_table")
public class User extends CommonBean {


@IgnoreMe
@Transient
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@OnlyNumber(message="Role Id Can be Only Number") //Custom Annotation
@Column(name="ROLE_ID")
private Long roleId;

........

}
```

Validation dependency added :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Project Details :**
- Spring Boot 1.3.1

When i run the application i get error message on jsp saying **Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long' for property 'roleId'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"**

instead i should get custom error message **Role Id Can be Only Number**
when i checked log in isValid method of my custom validator i get null  for parameter inside the method  .

May be something wrong with config or i am missing something

Answer (score 0):

I think you pojo needs to have roleId as type String. Also, validator should be ConstraintValidator

Problem with current code is that its already trying to convert String -> Long. So input is not valid number than setting roleId itself would fail with "java.lang.NumberFormatException"